# Adding rows to different dataframe programatically

Tags: r

Im creating a dataframe dynamically and Im using custom names to refer to those data frames.How ever, I can succesfully create the data frames dynamically and add information individually but manually when i try to add a record to it it will run the action but nothing happens. I can open the data frame and it shows as empty

```
#Extract unique machines on the system 
machines <- unique(wo_raw$MACHINE)
for(machine in machines){
  #Check if the machine is present on current data frames or has a record
  if(exists(machine) && is.data.frame(get(machine))){
    #Machine already exists on the system
    cat(machine," is a dataframe","\n")

    netlbs <- subset(wo_raw,((wo_raw$TYPE =="T" & wo_raw$TYPE2=="E") | (wo_raw$TYPE == "T" & is.na(wo_raw$TYPE2))) & wo_raw$WEEK<=curWeek & wo_raw$MACHINE == machine & wo_raw$YEAR == curYear,select = NET_LBS)

    scraplbs<- subset(wo_raw,((wo_raw$TYPE =="T" & wo_raw$TYPE2=="E") | (wo_raw$TYPE == "T" & is.na(wo_raw$TYPE2))) & wo_raw$WEEK<=curWeek & wo_raw$MACHINE == machine & wo_raw$YEAR == curYear,select = SCRAP_LBS)

    if(is.data.frame(netlbs) && nrow(netlbs)!=0){
      totalNet<- sum(netlbs)
      totalScrap<- sum(scraplbs)
      scrapRate <- percent(totalScrap/(sum(totalNet,totalScrap)),accuracy = 2)
      tempDf<-data.frame(curYear,curMonth,curDay,curWeek,totalNet,totalScrap,scrapRate)
      names(tempDf)<-c("year","month","day","week","net_lbs","scrap_lbs","scrap_rate")

      cat("Total Net lbs for ",machine,": ",totalNet,"\n")
      cat("Total Scrap lbs for ",machine,": ",totalScrap,"\n")
      cat("Total Scrap Rate for ",machine,": ",scrapRate,"\n")
      #machine<-rbind(get(machine),tempDf)
      #assign(machine,rbind(machine,tempDf))
      add_row(get(machine),year=curYear,
                           month=curMonth,
                           day=curDay,
                           week=curWeek,
                           net_lbs=totalNet,
                           scrap_lbs=totalScrap,
                           scrap_rate=scrapRate)
      cat("added row \n")
    }
    #info<-c(curYear,curMonth,curDay,curWeek,netlbs)
    #cat("Total Net lbs: ",netlbs,"\n")
    #netlbs <-NULL


  }else{
    cat("Creating machine dataframe: ",machine,"\n")
    #Create a dataframe labeled with machine name contining
    #date information, net lbs,scrap lbs and scrap rate
    assign(paste0(machine,""),data.frame(year=integer(),
                                         month=integer(),
                                         day=integer(),
                                         week=integer(),
                                         net_lbs=double(),
                                         scrap_lbs=double(),
                                         scrap_rate=integer()
                                          )
          )
    #machine$year<-curYear

  }
  #machine<-NULL


}
```

All the functions that I've tried are in commented lines from previous answers found on Stack Overflow. I did get working with a for but i dont think that would be really feasible since it will consume a lot of resources  plus it doesn't work well when handling various data types . Does anybody have an idea of whats going on, I don't have an error to go by.

Answer (score -1):

I think your code needs quite a lot of cleanup. Make sure you know for yourself at each step what exactly you are handling.

Some hints:

- Try to make your code self-contained. If I run your code, I get an error right away, as I don't have wo_raw defined. I understand it's some kind of data.frame, but exactly what is in there? What do I need to do to try to run your code? Also with variables like `curYear`. I get that it needs to be 2019, but I need to type an awful lot to just get to the problem, I can't just copy-paste.
- If you use any libraries, please also include a line for them. I don't know what `add_row` does or is supposed to do. So I also don't know if that's where your expectations are wrong?
- Try to make your code minimal before posting it here. I like the comments and `cat`s sprinkled throughout, but why a line such as `netlbs <- subset(wo_raw,((wo_raw$TYPE =="T" & wo_raw$TYPE2=="E") | (wo_raw$TYPE == "T" & is.na(wo_raw$TYPE2))) & wo_raw$WEEK<=curWeek & wo_raw$MACHINE == machine & wo_raw$YEAR == curYear,select = NET_LBS)`? For this problem, just something like `subset(wo_raw, wo_raw$mach==machine, net)` would suffice
- I get that the code works, but try to work out where you are using what kind of objects. `if (is.data.frame(netlbs)) {total=sum(netlbs)}` may work, but summing a data.frame while you actually just need a column leads to confusion.
- When using variables to store the names of other variables such as you are doing, be **very** aware of what you are actually refering to. For that reason, it's generally advisable to steer clear of these constructs, it's almost always easier to store your results in a list or something similar
- Come to that: the variable `machine` is *not* a data.frame, it's a `character`. That `character` is the *name* of another variable, which is a data.frame. So (commented out) I see some instances of `machine <- NULL` and `machine$year`, those are wrong. As is `rbind(machine, ...)`, as machine is not a data.frame

That being said, I think you got close with the `assign`-statement.
Does `assign(machine,rbind(get(machine),tempDf))` work?

Comment: Im trying to edit my post as after I posted I realized that you do not have all variables and/or libraries in there. It wont let me edit the post. However the assign statement works. I GOT IT WORKING!!!

Comment: Good to hear that!

Comment: I was forgetting to store the result in a variable, so i created a temporary data frame and stored it in there to then replace it with the binded dataframes @Emil Bode, thanks for your feedback